when running conda update --all, remember manual channel specification / pin packages to specific channel
I usually install packages from the default channels, but occasionally, I want the package from conda-forge instead. So I have setup conda-forge as the second priority channel
>conda config --append channels conda-forge
>conda config --show channels
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge

Now lets say I want to install nlopt from conda-forge, while keeping all other packages on the default channel:
conda install conda-forge::nlopt

Then later, when I update all the packages, I want to keep nlopt on conda-forge, but conda wants to change the channel
>conda update --all
...
The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  nlopt              conda-forge::nlopt-2.7.1-py311hdac7a7~ --> pkgs/main::nlopt-2.7.1-hd77b12b_0

How do I manually pin a package to a specific channel so conda never changes the channel during updates?

There are two options:
You can add a pinned file at $PREFIX/conda-meta/pinned with a list of packages pinnings:
# contents of /path/to/conda-env/conda-meta/pinned
conda-forge::nlopt

Or you can pin through the conda config for that environment using the --env flag:
conda config --env --append pinned_packages conda-forge::nlopt

